# Magento 2 api rest update product per store id not working

Tags: magento2, api

I did all the changes that user Emizen-tech https://stackoverflow.com/users/6333615/emizen-tech recomend:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37744874/magento2-rest-api-save-product-detail-per-store-view-not-working

but when I send my PUT request for changing a price it does not work:

http://www.myshop.com/index.php/rest/V1/products/mysku/storeID=0

The result is:

```
{ "message": "Invalid product data: %1" "parameters": [1]

    0: "Invalid attribute set entity type"

}
```

The issue is how I pass the parameter `Store Id` in the URL.
How can I separate the `sku` from the parameter `Store Id`??

Comment: How can I set a value for a custom attribute that has store view scope, but I want to set the same value for all stores. I tried this endpoint: rest/all/V1/products/<sku> But when I get the sku by the store view endpoint, the custom attribute doesn't change.
There is any way to set one value to all stores? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I´ve just found the solution ! Instead of using store number I used the name I gave it.

This is the URL that worked now: `{/rest/skyhub/V1/products/sku}`

skyhub is the name of my store with id 2. :) Hope this helps you too.

===============

I am writing an answer cause I cannot add comments yet. I am facing the same issue. Were you able to solve it ?

I am using the URL: `{/rest/2/V1/products/sku}` to update store 2 but I get error.

My JSON: `{"product":{"visibility":1}}`

Error: `{"message":"Specified request cannot be processed."}`

Comment: rest/<store_code>/V1/products/<sku>

Answer (score 0):

you can update the product by the following endpoint

```
rest/<store_code>/V1/products/<sku>
```